# rank sum score calculation on a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

> ```
>  Name1    Name2    Name3   
>    1        1         1    
>   -1       -1         1
>    1       -1         1   
>    1       -1         1     
>   -1       -1         1
> ```

I would like to perform a sort of rank-sum test for each column so that:

starting from the first element of each column (so for each list of my data.frame)
if the second element is equal to the first (for ex: 1 and 1) the score will be increased by an unit  because they are equals, otherwise the score will be decreased by an unity (because they are unequals, for ex: 1 and -1).

Ex: column "Name1"
first element = 1 : score = 1 (starting position)
second element = -1: score = 0 (1 unit is removed from the previous score (1) because 1 != -1)
third element = 1 : score = 1 (you are initializing the score to 1. Every time you initialize, the score is +1).
fourth element = 1 : score = 2 ( previous score 1 plus 1 unit because the third and the fourth elements are equals)
fifth element = -1: score = 1 (previous score 2 - 1 unit because fourth element != fifth element).

column "Name2"
first element = 1 : score = 1 (starting position)
second element = -1: score = 0 (1 unit is removed from the previous score (1) because 1 != -1)
third element = -1: score = 1 (you are reinitializing the score)
fourth element = -1: score = 2 (third element is equal to the fourth so the previous score will be increased by 1 unit)
fifth element = -1: score = 3 (fourth element is equal to the fifth one so the previous score, so 2, will be increased by 1 unit)

So the counter will increase or decrease  the score  of a number == 1 if the element in the ranking is equal or different by the previous one and it will be initialized to 1 every time it goes to 0.

The final goal is to  give an higher score to the equals and consecutive elements in the rank respect to the random ones.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: And what you want to obtain as a result? One final value? The sequence of step-by-step values? Give please an example of the result on the certain data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this function:

```
f <- function(x)
{
  2 * sum(tail(x, -1)==head(x, -1)) - length(x) + 1
}
```

It computes the score you propose as the number of elements that are equal to the previous one minus the number of elements that differ. Since this last number is complementary to the first, the function can be written in the simplified form above.

Now if you want to apply that to all columns of a dataframe, simply use `sapply`:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
 Name1    Name2    Name3   
   1        1         1    
  -1       -1         1
   1       -1         1   
   1       -1         1     
  -1       -1         1
")
sapply(dat, f)
# Name1 Name2 Name3 
#    -2     2     4
```

Comment: the way I understand OP the output should be `1, -1, 5`

Comment: Hi guys, my point is a little bit different and your help doesn't fit exactly my question. My idea is to give an higher score to the equals and consecutive elements in the rank respect to the random ones. Probably I have to edit my question. But anyway thank you a lot!

Comment: Hi Ferdinand.kraft! Even if this answer doesn't fit my problem at all like the answer of DWin, this solution highlight, even if not in the best way, the difference between the three columns. So thank you a lot again!!!

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood you correctly...

```
d <- read.table(text="Name1    Name2    Name3   
   1        1         1    
  -1       -1         1
   1       -1         1   
   1       -1         1     
  -1       -1         1", header=TRUE)


f1 <- function(score, pair) {
    if (score == 0) pair[1]
    else if (as.logical(diff(pair))) score - 1
    else score + 1
}

f2 <- function(col) {
    lagged <- embed(col, 2)
    Reduce(f1, split(lagged, seq(nrow(lagged))), init=1)
}

lapply(d, f2)
# $Name1
# [1] 1
# 
# $Name2
# [1] -1
# 
# $Name3
# [1] 5
```

Comment: @Elb that doesn't match your description, because when you get -1 in Name2, the element and the next element are the same, so you'd add 1 and get 0 according to your OP

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to your subsequent question and not the first one, which I believe Matthew Plourde has answered to.

To get a measure of the rank you want, you could for instance count the sum of the lengths of pieces of your columns that have the same number more than once in a row. E.g in the example below you could add 3 and 2 and get a rank of 5.

```
x = c(1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1)
rle(x)
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:4] 1 1 3 2
#  values : num [1:4] 1 -1 1 -1
```

To put it in a function:

```
rank = function(x) {
  x.rle = rle(x)
  sum(x.rle$lengths[x.rle$lengths > 1])
}

sapply(OP_dat, rank)
#Name1 Name2 Name3 
#    2     4     5
```

Comment: Hi eddi! Thank you a lot for your help and sorry for the mistake. Even if you don't match exactly my point with your proposed function, I think this is a good answer because in any case the score is higher in Name2 respect to Name1 (randomly distributed elements) and lower to Name3 as expected due to the element 1 in Name2 column. So this fit exactly what I' m trying to highlight in my work. Thank you a lot!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add one to an equality test to construct an index of 1's and 2's to select from c(-1,1)

```
func <- function(x) 1+                  # your "starting position"
                    sum( c(-1, 1)[1+    # convert from 0/1 to 1/2
                                  (x[-1] == x[-length(x)]) ])

> sapply(dat, func)
Name1 Name2 Name3 
   -2     2     4
```

Comment: If this unexplained downvote is from the OP, the way to get better answers is to make your question clearer.

Comment: It's from me, same reason as the other downvote, while OP seems to be confused about what they want, this doesn't match OP description.

Comment: The OP has contradictory (and very confusing) specs for the problem. I chose to implement the first one. You are choosing the second one.

Comment: Hi DWin! Even if this answer doesn't fit my problem at all, this solution highlight, even if not in the best way, the difference between the three columns. So thank you a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably this will help.

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
 Name1    Name2    Name3   
   1        1         1    
  -1       -1         1
   1       -1         1   
   1       -1         1     
  -1       -1         1
")

f <- function(x) {
  tail(cumsum(x), 1)
}

sapply(dat, f)

#Name1 Name2 Name3 
#    1    -3     5
```

And if you want to compare these results you may take `abs` values.

Comment: the problem with this idea is that something like `c(1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1)` would score very low